# How to write a sql query to get this output?

Tags: php, mysql

I have database table with the follwoing fields:

```
id, loan_no, installment, status
```

which has loan information like

if a loan has 24 installments there will be 24 rows which contains same loan_no and installment status which is paid or unpiad.

So I want to get the loan_no's which has all installments status = paid.

Is it possible to write a one query to get result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT loan_no FROM your_table
WHERE loan_no NOT IN
  SELECT DISTINCT loan_no FROM your_table
  WHERE status = 'unpaid')
GROUP BY loan_no
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
select distinct
        i.loan_no,
        i.status
    from
        info as i
        left outer join info as i2
            on i.loan_no = i2.loan_no and i2.status = 'unpaid'
    where
        i.status = 'paid'
        and
        i2.loan_no is null
;
```

Comment: thanks this also works but taking longer to generate results though

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT loan_no FROM loan
WHERE loan_no NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT loan_no FROM loan WHERE status = 'unpaid')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT loan_no FROM table where status = "paid" group by loan_no;
```

Comment: Your query returns loans having some unpaid status: OP needs loan that have ALL status = 'paid'...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT A.loan_no FROM (
    SELECT loan_no, COUNT(status) AS installments
    WHERE status = 'paid' 
    GROUP BY loan_no, status
) AS A
WHERE A.installments = 24
```

So all loans will always have 24 payments?  And if you want to pull loan_no for all loans that have had all 24 payments made, then something like the above will work.

Comment: OP says _"if a loan has 24 installments"_, he's providing an example ;)

Comment: yeah installment amount is not always 24.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT loan_no FROM YOUR_TABLE
WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE status = 'unpaid') GROUP BY loan_no
```

Comment: It's wrong: you're taking unpaid installments (with subquery) and removing them from table... so you get paid installments, but not loans with ALL installments paid ;)